# How to have default and custom wheelEvent

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqt5

I have this function that overwrites default behaviour of `wheelEvent` (changes font sizes in `QTextEdit`, behaves like zoom in/out), but since that class is inheriting from `QTextEdit` I have lost default wheel behaviour which is **scrolling** when the mouse is anywhere inside it.

So my question is: How to have normal behaviour for wheel event, and "something_else" for Ctrl + wheel event.

Note: function called with Ctrl modifier is made I just don't know how to combine it with normal behaviour.

```
 def wheelEvent(self, event):

        if (event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier):
            self.bindWheel(event)

        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the default implementation of your `QTextEdit` super class. Assuming you are using Python 3:

```
def wheelEvent(self, event):
    if (event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier):
        self.bindWheel(event)
    else:
        super().wheelEvent(event)
```

Comment: Surely the `super` call should go in the else branch.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i needed.